# Can't add navigation to Bottom Bar in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use the **salomon_bottom_bar** package from flutter unless it has no way to add routing through this bar!

```
SalomonBottomBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
        title: Text("Likes"),
        selectedColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
```

Is there a way to add routing to this package? I'd be glad if anyone can help!
here is the link to the package doc: [salomon_bottom_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/salomon_bottom_bar)

Comment: After you changed your index, try to navigate a page. If your index is 1 navigate somewhere and else.

Answer (score 0):

```
    bottomNavigationBar: SalomonBottomBar(
              currentIndex: _currentIndex,
              onTap: (i){
               setState(){
                _currentIndex = i;
               //and then navigate through pages
}
},
              items: [
                /// Home
                SalomonBottomBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  title: Text("Home"),
                  selectedColor: Colors.purple,
                ),
    
                /// Likes
                SalomonBottomBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                  title: Text("Likes"),
                  selectedColor: Colors.pink,
                ),
    
                /// Search
                SalomonBottomBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                  title: Text("Search"),
                  selectedColor: Colors.orange,
                ),
    
                /// Profile
                SalomonBottomBarItem(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                  title: Text("Profile"),
                  selectedColor: Colors.teal,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```